# How do I copy all elements and children between two elements into a temp element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
context = document.createElement("span");
start_element = my_start_element;
end_element = my_end_element;

// some how iterate through here (assuming start and end are different elements)
[start_element .. end_element].each(function(current_element){
   context.append(current_element);
});
```

pretty straight forward, just don't know how to do the loop part with the start and end nodes. =\

Comment: What is "between"? The DOM is not a flattened list but a hierarchical model.

Comment: Do you want to know how to copy elements? Or how to iterate through elements? Or how to append/remove elements?

Comment: Can we assume anything about the relationship between start and end elements? Are they always siblings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also accomplish this with the plain `DOM` and `DocumentFragment`.

Assuming that **the start and end nodes are siblings** and you have the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p id="start">paragraph 2</p>
    <p>paragraph 3</p>
    <ul id="end">
        <li>paragraph 4</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph 5</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following JS will copy the nodes and insert them in another place.

```
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var end = document.getElementById('end');

var newcontainer = document.createElement('div');
newcontainer.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

var clonednodes = document.createDocumentFragment();

var node = start, lastnode = null;
while (lastnode!=end){
    // note that cloneNode(true) will lead to duplicate id attributes
    clonednodes.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
    lastnode = node;
    node = lastnode.nextSibling;
}

newcontainer.appendChild(clonednodes);

document.body.appendChild(newcontainer);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @pimvdb pointed out in the question comments, "The DOM is not a flattened list but a hierarchical model."

So to make some sense of your question, I have to make assumptions.

I'm going to assume that your `start_element` and `end_element` are siblings, and you are trying to find all dom elements that are also siblings but appear between the two. In otherwords, I'm assuming you are talking about one particular flat subsection of the DOM. If my assumption is wrong, please disregard this answer. If my assumption is right, then you can iterate over all the siblings like this, and only match the ones in between:

```
var siblings = $(start_element).parent().children();
var currently_between = false;
var matches = [];
siblings.each(function() {
    if (this == start_element) currently_between = true;
    else if (this == end_element) currently_between = false; 
    else if (currently_between) matches.push(this);
});
// "matches" contains the in-between elements
```

Note that this assumes `start_element` and `end_element` are plain DOM objects, not jquery-extended objects. If they are jquery-extended, then the checks should be like `if (this == start_element.get(0))`.

Note also that there is a [jquery siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method, but we used `$(start_element).parent().children()` instead because we want the original `start_element` to be part of the group. The `sublings()` method would leave it out.

Comment: You could, I think, combine `siblings()` with [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to retain the original `start_element` as part of the group.